# Right way to clone objects / arrays during setState in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I start with:

```
constructor() {
   super();
      this.state = {
         lists: ['Dogs','Cats'], 
         items: {Dogs: [{name: "Snoopy"}, {name: "Lola"}, {name: "Sprinkles"}], 
                 Cats: [{name: "Felidae"}, {name: "Garfiled"}, {name: "Cat in the Hat"}] }             
   };

}
```

then I have my addItem function:

```
handleAddItem(s) {      

  var key = Object.keys(s)[0];
  var value = s[key];

  var allItems = {...this.state.items};

      allItems[key].push({name: value});    

      this.setState({items: allItems});
}
```

elsewhere I define s as:

```
var s={};
   s[this.props.idName] = this.refs.id.value;
```

This works but I'm wondering if this is the right way to add an element into one of the keys in items.  AllItems is really pointing to this.state.items and I thought it should be a deep copy but I'm not sure how to do that.

It seems like items is an object that holds key/value pairs where the value is an array.  Is that correct?  Where can I go to learn how to manipulate a structure like that?

Comment: but it seems like we are directly changing state since allItems is really pointing to this.state.items

Comment: Any reason why you don't just do `this.state = { dogs: [], cats: [] }`. Might make life a little easier.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I personally rely on this deep copy strategy.
`JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object))` rather than `spread` operator because it got me into weird bugs while dealing with nested objects or multi dimensional arrays.

`spread` operator does not do a deep copy if I am correct and will lead to state mutations with **NESTED** objects in React.

Please run through the code to get a better understanding of what is happening between the two. Imagine that is the state variable that you mutate using `spread` operator.

```js
const obj = {Dogs: [{name: "Snoopy"}, {name: "Lola"}, {name: "Sprinkles"}], Cats: [{name: "Felidae"}, {name: "Garfiled"}, {name: "Cat in the Hat"}] };

const newObj = {...obj};
console.log("BEFORE SPREAD COPY MUTATION")

console.log("NEW OBJ: " + newObj.Dogs[0].name); //Snoopy
console.log("OLD OBJ: " + obj.Dogs[0].name); //Snoopy

newObj.Dogs[0].name = "CLONED Snoopy";

console.log("AFTER SPREAD COPY MUTATION")

console.log("NEW OBJ: " + newObj.Dogs[0].name); // CLONED Snoopy
console.log("OLD OBJ: " + obj.Dogs[0].name); // CLONED Snoopy

// Even after using the spread operator the changed on the cloned object are affected to the old object. This happens always in cases of nested objects.

// My personal reliable deep copy

console.log("*********DEEP COPY***********");

console.log("BEFORE DEEP COPY MUTATION")
deepCopyObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));


console.log("NEW OBJ: " + newObj.Dogs[0].name); //CLONED Snoopy
console.log("OLD OBJ: " + obj.Dogs[0].name); // CLONED Snoopy
console.log("DEEP OBJ: " + deepCopyObj.Dogs[0].name); //CLONED Snoopy


deepCopyObj.Dogs[0].name = "DEEP CLONED Snoopy";

console.log("AFTER DEEP COPY MUTATION")
console.log("NEW OBJ: " + newObj.Dogs[0].name); // CLONED Snoopy
console.log("OLD OBJ: " + obj.Dogs[0].name); // CLONED Snoopy
console.log("DEEP OBJ: " + deepCopyObj.Dogs[0].name); // DEEP CLONED Snoopy
```

Now, if you wanted to do a deep copy on your object change the handler to this

```
handleAddItem(s) {      

  var key = Object.keys(s)[0];
  var value = s[key];

  var allItems = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.items));

      allItems[key].push({name: value});    

      this.setState({items: allItems});
}
```

Comment: Be aware that this could lead to data loss. Dates for example.

Comment: seems inefficient?

Comment: Yes, this answer is simple and clean but it's definitely slower than some other methods. That may not matter in a lot of cases, though. According to this benchmark I found Lodash `cloneDeep` is about 60% faster. https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/2751/0/lodash-clonedeep-vs-json-clone

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to add a bit more info about cloning arrays. You can call [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice), providing 0 as the first argument:

```
const clone = myArray.slice(0);
```

The code above creates clone of the original array; keep in mind that if objects exist in your array, the references are kept; i.e. the code above does not do a "deep" clone of the array contents.

Comment: Like said in the accepted post this will NOT work, I have an array of objects with values that are also objects, and the ONLY thing that worked properly is the accepted answer. This slice method was STILL updating my inner object vales in BOTH arrays, state, and  'copy', lost hours on this.

Answer (score 2):

One issue might be that `var allItems = {...this.state.items};` will only do a shallow clone of `this.state.items`. So when you push data into this array, it will change the existing array before you call `setState`.

You could use [Immutable.js](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/) to solve this issue.

```
import { List, fromJS, Map } from 'immutable';

constructor() {
   super();
      this.state = {
       lists: List(['Dogs','Cats']), 
       items: fromJS({
        Dogs: [
          { name: "Snoopy" },
          ...
        ],
        Cats: [
          { name: "Felidae" },
          ...
        ]
      })
   };
}
```

and then your add function would be as follow:

```
handleAddItem(s) {      
  var key = Object.keys(s)[0];
  var value = s[key];

  var allItems = this.state.items.set(key, Map({ name: value }));
  this.setState({ items: allItems });
}
```

Just a thought!

Comment: when I try your map function I get Constructor Map requires 'new'

Comment: what does that mean?

Comment: i added `{ Map } from 'immutable';` in the very top line so that Map doesn't throw the error you mentioned above

Answer (score 2):

The chosen answer was a miracle and huge props to  Nandu Kalidindi, I was having bugs with nested arrays inside of objects that I was updating in my project and was not understanding the concept of "deep" or "nested" arrays and objects not being copied to a new object.

This is my take on his fix and made it look a little more appealing to me and works just as good!

I utilize `lodash` and found their `_.cloneDeep()` function to serve my updating state needs.

[Lodash _.cloneDeep()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#cloneDeep)

I learned that mapping out updated arrays preventing any bugs was the best way to treat that kind of problem, but I was cloning entire objects with nested arrays that were mutating the old object's arrays in the state.

This is my answer.

```
const state = {
    fields: {
        "caNyDcSDVb": {
            id: "caNyDcSDVb",
            name: "test1",
            type: "text",
            options: ["A", "B", "C"]
        }
    },
};

const FieldCopy = (id) => {
    const newCopiedField = _.cloneDeep(state.fields[id]);
    newCopiedField.id = nanoid(10);
    return {
        ...state,
        fields: {
            ...state.fields,
            newCopiedField[id]: newCopiedField
        }
    };
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a one line deep-copy. This is for 'single level' deep objects. If your object has other objects / arrarys, you'll need to use a recursive method.

```
const clone = array_of_objects.map( x => { return {...x}} )
```

Comment: This helped me fix the error in single line
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to maintain *immutability* when setting your state within React (so, always make a new object or clone), and since the spread `...` operator doesn't clone deeply, you should make use of **structuredClone()**.

Take a look at the MDN:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/structuredClone

> The global structuredClone() method creates a [deep clone](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Deep_copy) of a given value using the [structured clone algorithm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Structured_clone_algorithm).
>
> The method also allows [transferable objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Transferable_objects) in the original value to be transferred rather than cloned to the new object. Transferred objects are detached from the original object and attached to the new object; they are no longer accessible in the original object.

This is more or less the *modern replacement* (as of this post at least) for the `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(yourObject))` method of cloning.

Here's a functional component example:

```js
const nestedAnimals = {
    lists: ['Dogs', 'Cats'],
    items: {
        Dogs: [
            {name: "Snoopy"},
            {name: "Lola"},
            {name: "Sprinkles"}
        ],
        Cats: [
            {name: "Felidae"},
            {name: "Garfiled"},
            {name: "Cat in the Hat"}
        ]
    }
}

const someComponent = (props) => {
    const [animals, setAnimals] = useState(nestedAnimals)
    const [selectedList, setSelectedList] = useState(animals.lists[0])
    const [animalInput, setAnimalInput] = useState("")
    
    // Handler for adding a new animal to our deeply nested object.
    function addAnimal(event) {
        const newAnimal = {name: animalInput}
        // Here's where the deep cloning magic happens.
        const newAnimals = structuredClone(animals)
        newAnimals.items[selectedList].push(newAnimal)
        // Now you've updated your state in an immutable fashion.
        setAnimals(newAnimals)
    }

    // Handler for swapping lists.
    function changeList(event) {
        setSelectedList(event.target.value)
    }
    
    // Handler for storing the value from the input field as it changes.
    function changeAnimalInput(event) {
        setAnimalInput(event.target.value)
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <input type="text" value={animalInput} onChange={changeAnimalInput}/>
            <button onClick={addAnimal}>Add Animal</button>
            <select onChange={changeList}>
                {animals.lists.map(list => <option value={list}>{list}</option>)}
            </select>
            <ul>
                {animals.items[selectedList].map(animal => <li>{animal.name}</li>)}
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Luke Dupin, this solution helped me!

```
const clone = items.map( x => ({...x}) )
```

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32716992)