# React.js - Having trouble creating a new invoice within my project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-state

I'm newer to React and could really use a hand understanding how to create a new invoice within my project.

**The Issue:**
Currently, I can create a new Invoice no problem as shown in the images below. I changed the inputs to some test data to help illustrate the issue I'm having.

[image]

[image]

Here's the overhead view showing the total number of invoices within the stack so far.

[image]

The problem occurs when I go to create a second new invoice. It keeps all of the old data from my first one that I modified, even though I can click them and modify them independently from one another. The weird part is... only some of the values are staying the same while others can become independent from one another...

This is directly after creating a second invoice:

[image]

I changed the second invoice to all new data:

[image]

And this is the result within invoice 1:

[image]

And now when I create a 3rd new invoice:

[image]

This tells me that they're connected somehow.. A direct link to my project is here: https://github.com/Brent-W-Anderson/invoice-pdf/tree/invoices

Otherwise, I think the problem is how I'm creating a new invoice or how I'm modifying the data within it. Please look at line 113 where I modify the invoice or line 94 where I am creating a new one. I need all the help I can get, thank you!

https://github.com/Brent-W-Anderson/invoice-pdf/blob/invoices/src/components/app.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Moment from 'moment';

//components
import LoginSignUp from './login-signup/login-signup';
import Navigation from './navigation/navigation';
import Pages from './pages/pages';

//data
import UsersJSON from '../data/users.json'; // some test data for now. going to connect a database later.
import AppJSON from '../data/app.json';

//styling
import 'fontsource-roboto';
import '../styles/app.css';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    loggedIn: false, // set to true to bypass logging in.
    transitionOut: false,
    activeUser: "", // can put whatever name you want here if loggedIn is set to true.
    activePage: "invoices",
    invoiceMode: "view", // dont change this unless you want to start with a specific manageable invoice.
    userData: {}, // set to the specific array index from the users if looking for some sample data.
    users: UsersJSON,
    appData: AppJSON
  };

  setActiveModeView = (clicked) => { // view all of the invoices
    this.setState({
      invoiceMode: "view"
    });
  }

  setActiveModeEdit = () => { // view a specific manageable/ editable invoice
    this.setState({
      invoiceMode: "edit"
    });
  }

  login = (userData) => { // login and store the users data for component use.
    let user = this;
    let username = userData.personalInfo.name;

    this.setState({
      userData: userData,
      transitionOut: false
    });

    setTimeout(function() { // let the app animate out before logging in.
      user.setState({
        loggedIn: true,
        activeUser: username
      });
    }, 1000);
  };

  logout = () => { // logout and reset the users data.
    let user = this;

    this.setState({
      transitionOut: true
    });

    setTimeout(function() { // let the app animate out before logging out.
      user.setState({
        loggedIn: false,
        userData: {},
        activePage: "invoices",
        invoiceMode: "view",
        activeUser: ""
      });
    }, 1500);
  }

  setActivePage = (page) => { // changing tabs
    let pageName = page.target.innerHTML.toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g, '');
    let app = this;

    if(pageName !== "invoices") { // change view mode back to defaults if not within invoices.
      setTimeout(function() {
        app.setActiveModeView();
      }, 500);
    }else {
      app.setActiveModeView("invoices");
    };

    this.setState({
      activePage: pageName
    });
  };


  createInvoice = idx => {
    console.log(UsersJSON[0].invoices[0]);

    this.setState(prevState => ({
      userData: {
        ...prevState.userData,
        invoices: [
          ...prevState.userData.invoices,
          {
            ...UsersJSON[0].invoices[0],
            invoiceID: idx + 1,
            date: Moment(new Date()).format("YYYY-MM-DD")
          }
        ]
      }
    }));
  };


  modifyInvoice = (userData, invoiceIdx, clientIdx, otherInputSelected, otherData) => (inputSelected) => { // editing specific invoice data and storing it back in state
    const app = this;
    let targetID, newVal;

    if(inputSelected !== undefined) {
      targetID = inputSelected.target.id;
      newVal = inputSelected.target.value;
    }else {
      switch(otherInputSelected) {
        case "billToEmail":
          targetID = otherInputSelected;
          newVal = otherData;
          break;

        case "fromEmail":
          targetID = otherInputSelected;
          newVal = otherData;
          break;

        default:
          console.warn("no other input selected to save to app state.");
      };
    }
    let newUserData = userData;

    function overwriteState() {
      app.setState({
        userData: newUserData
      });
    }

    switch(targetID) { // which input would you like to modify?
      case "invoiceName":
        newUserData.invoices[invoiceIdx].invoiceName = newVal;
        overwriteState();
        break;

      // BILL TO

      case "billToName":
        newUserData.invoices[invoiceIdx].toName = newVal;
        overwriteState();
        break;

      case "billToEmail":
        newUserData.invoices[invoiceIdx].toEmail = newVal;
        overwriteState();
        break;

      case "billToStreet":
        newUserData.invoices[invoiceIdx].toAddress.street = newVal;
        overwriteState();
        break;

      case "billToCityState":
        newUserData.invoices[invoiceIdx].toAddress.cityState = newVal;
        overwriteState();
        break;

      case "billToZip":
        newUserData.invoices[invoiceIdx].toAddress.zip = newVal;
        overwriteState();
        break;

      case "billToPhone":
        newUserData.invoices[invoiceIdx].toPhone = newVal;
        overwriteState();
        break;

      // FROM

      case "fromName":
        newUserData.invoices[invoiceIdx].fromName = newVal;
        overwriteState();
        break;

      case "fromEmail":
        newUserData.invoices[invoiceIdx].fromEmail = newVal;
        overwriteState();
        break;

      case "fromStreet":
        newUserData.invoices[invoiceIdx].fromAddress.street = newVal;
        overwriteState();
        break;

      case "fromCityState":
        newUserData.invoices[invoiceIdx].fromAddress.cityState = newVal;
        overwriteState();
        break;

      case "fromZip":
        newUserData.invoices[invoiceIdx].fromAddress.zip = newVal;
        overwriteState();
        break;

      case "fromPhone":
        newUserData.invoices[invoiceIdx].fromPhone = newVal;
        overwriteState();
        break;

      // DETAILS

      case "date":
        newUserData.invoices[invoiceIdx].date = newVal;
        overwriteState();
        break;

      case "description":
        newUserData.invoices[invoiceIdx].items.description = newVal;
        overwriteState();
        break;

      case "rate":
        newUserData.invoices[invoiceIdx].items.rate = newVal;
        overwriteState();
        break;

      case "qty":
        newUserData.invoices[invoiceIdx].items.qty = newVal;
        overwriteState();
        break;

      case "additionalDetails":
        newUserData.invoices[invoiceIdx].items.additionalDetails = newVal;
        overwriteState();
        break;

      default:
        console.warn("something went wrong... selected target input:");
        console.warn(targetID);
    }
  };


  deleteInvoice = (invoice, idx) => { // deletes an invoice
    let newUserData = this.state.userData;
    newUserData.invoices.splice(idx, 1);

    for(var x = 0; x < newUserData.invoices.length; x++) {
      newUserData.invoices[x].invoiceID = (x + 1).toString();
    }

    this.setState({
      userData: newUserData
    });
  }


  render() {
    let app = this.state;

    if(app.loggedIn) { // if logged in
      return (
        <div className="app">
          <Navigation
            activeUser={app.activeUser}
            setActivePage={this.setActivePage}
            activePage={app.activePage}
            appData={app.appData}
            logout={this.logout}
          />
          <Pages
            setActiveModeView={this.setActiveModeView}
            setActiveModeEdit={this.setActiveModeEdit}
            invoiceMode={app.invoiceMode}
            activePage={app.activePage}
            appData={app.appData}
            transitionOut={app.transitionOut}
            userData={app.userData}
            createInvoice={this.createInvoice}
            modifyInvoice={this.modifyInvoice}
            deleteInvoice={this.deleteInvoice}
          />
        </div>
      );
    }else { // if not logged in
      return (
        <div className="app">
          <LoginSignUp
            login={this.login}
            users={app.users}
          />
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe one option would be to change:

```
      case "billToStreet":
        newUserData.invoices[invoiceIdx].toAddress.street = newVal;
        overwriteState();
        break;
```

to:

```
      case "billToStreet":
        newUserData.invoices[invoiceIdx].toAddress = { ...newUserData.invoices[invoiceIdx].toAddress, street: newVal };
        overwriteState();
        break;
```

and do the same for the other address fields.

I'm not sure why but I suspect that all of your toAddress entries are referencing the same object.

Comment: Wow thanks, this actually fixed the problem. Why does this fix the issue though? Isn't it still assigning the value the same way just different syntax? I can't seem to get this solution to work for any of my line items with the details, rate, qty, etc..

Comment: I suspect that the root of the problem is in the createInvoice() function. ...UsersJSON[0].invoices[0] will be copying the toAddress and fromAddress from that source - except it's not a copy - when you create two invoices like this I think it's possible that both will be referencing the same toAddress found at UsersJSON[0].invoices[0].toAddress and will be updating that object. I think the code I supplied works because it creates a new object for toAddress instead of just updating the one being referenced, but possibly the better place to fix this would be in the createInvoice() function.

Comment: Okay so after a lot of snooping around and trial and error with google, I found the solution. The spread operator {} has issues with it mutating state. I found it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47624142/right-way-to-clone-objects-arrays-during-setstate-in-react    By simply changing the way I'm grabbing my template it completely solved my issue. Thanks again for the help, you pointed me in the right direction my friend =)