# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'amount' of object '#<Object>'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm fetching data from an API and then I save an array inside a state. While I'm trying to modify the specific field in object inside an array using input, I'm getting the following error: 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'amount' of object '#''.

**States (I'm using RTK Query):**

```
const { data: Florists_data, refetch } = useGetFloristQuery(Number(sessionStorage.getItem('florist_id')));
const [flowersData, setFlowersData] = useState(Florists_data?.florist[0].flowers);
const [tmpFlowers, setTmpFlowers] = useState(Florists_data?.florist[0].flowers);
```

**Update function:**

```
const updateFieldChanged = (index: number, e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement | HTMLInputElement>) => {
        let newArr = [...tmpFlowers!];
        newArr[index].amount = Number(e.target.value); //GETTING ERROR HERE
        setTmpFlowers(newArr);
    }
```

**Inputs:**

```
{flowersData?.map((flower, index) => {
  return (
    <>
      <div className={classes.Nested_Flower_Container} key={index}>
        <div className={classes.Nested_Flower_Name}>
          {flower.name}
        </div>
        <div className={classes.Nested_Flower_Input} style={{ marginRight: '0.2em' }}>
          <TextField
            id="Amount"
            label="Amount"
            variant="outlined"
            size="small"
            type="number"
            onChange={(e) => {
              updateFieldChanged(index, e);
            }}
            className={classes_2.root}
            />
        </div>
      </div>
    </>)
})}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spread operator normally creates a new object in memory, not just an address pointer. But when using it on an array of objects, it creates a second array like usual, but with all the objects inside being memory pointers. In short, what I believe is happening is the objects cant be changed because they're not copies. Try finding a deep clone code and testing of it works. (This is what's happening https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/335455578921107456/940745267324534825/MMAsMng1.png) which I also suspect is erroring out because you're modifying the state in an unapproved way

Comment: The answer guided me to the solution to the problem. The new array was not an independent copy. I solved my problem by doing a deep copy like that: 
let newArr = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(tmpFlowers!));
Found solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47624142/right-way-to-clone-objects-arrays-during-setstate-in-react

Comment: Yeah, they're not pretty solutions but they work.